# What's the reason behind the arrangement of "Indeed in that are signs for..."?

Tags: quran, tafseer, uloom-al-quran

In the Holy Qur'an, in the verses:

> وَمِنْ آيَاتِهِ أَنْ خَلَقَ لَكُم مِّنْ أَنفُسِكُمْ أَزْوَاجًا لِّتَسْكُنُوا إِلَيْهَا وَجَعَلَ بَيْنَكُم مَّوَدَّةً وَرَحْمَةً ۚ **إِنَّ فِي ذَٰلِكَ لَآيَاتٍ لِّقَوْمٍ يَتَفَكَّرُونَ** - 30:21
>   And of His signs is that He created for you from yourselves mates that you may find tranquillity in them; and He placed between you affection and mercy. **Indeed in that are signs for a people who give thought.**
>
> وَمِنْ آيَاتِهِ خَلْقُ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالْأَرْضِ وَاخْتِلَافُ أَلْسِنَتِكُمْ وَأَلْوَانِكُمْ ۚ **إِنَّ فِي ذَٰلِكَ لَآيَاتٍ لِّلْعَالِمِينَ** - 30:22
>   And of His signs is the creation of the heavens and the earth and the diversity of your languages and your colors. **Indeed in that are signs for those of knowledge.**
>
> وَمِنْ آيَاتِهِ مَنَامُكُم بِاللَّيْلِ وَالنَّهَارِ وَابْتِغَاؤُكُم مِّن فَضْلِهِ ۚ **إِنَّ فِي ذَٰلِكَ لَآيَاتٍ لِّقَوْمٍ يَسْمَعُونَ** - 30:23
>   And of His signs is your sleep by night and day and your seeking of His bounty. **Indeed in that are signs for a people who listen**.
>
> وَمِنْ آيَاتِهِ يُرِيكُمُ الْبَرْقَ خَوْفًا وَطَمَعًا وَيُنَزِّلُ مِنَ السَّمَاءِ مَاءً فَيُحْيِي بِهِ الْأَرْضَ بَعْدَ مَوْتِهَا ۚ **إِنَّ فِي ذَٰلِكَ لَآيَاتٍ لِّقَوْمٍ يَعْقِلُونَ** - 30:24
>   And of His signs is [that] He shows you the lightening [causing] fear and aspiration, and He sends down rain from the sky by which He brings to life the earth after its lifelessness. **Indeed in that are signs for a people who use reason**.

In the first one, Allah (may He be Exalted and Glorified) says "**who give thought**," then "**for those of knowledge**," then "**who listen**," then "**who use reason**."

In Surah An-Nahl, first (in ayah [10](https://quran.com/16/11) - [11](https://quran.com/16/11) - [12](https://quran.com/16/11) - [13](https://quran.com/16/11)) there's "**who believe**," then "**who give thought**," then "**who use reason**," then "**who remember**."

Secondly, in the same Surah, in ayat 65-69, it says "**who hear**," then "**who use reason**," then "**who give thought**."

Thirdly, in the same Surah, Allah (Subhannahu was ta'ala) only says ["**who believe**."](https://quran.com/16/11)

Of course, there are other examples in the Qur'an, but I want to know the reason of the arrangements of "**who give thought**," "**who hear**," "**who use reason**," "**of knowledge**," "**who remember**."

In Surah Ar-Rum, "**who give thought**" appears first, and in Surah An-Nahl, "**who give thought**" appears last.

Jazakum Allah khayran,

Comment: The question seems interesting, but I'm having some doubts whether or not it is answerable within the scope and limitation of our site. As it might be a matter on which one could even write a book.